# How to make popup help/info message?

Tags: javascript, jquery, messagebox

How do show pop up help messages in jquery?

I.e You might want to let the user know about a new feature, or might want to provide the user with help on how to use a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet to get started would be the j[Query Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) which is part of jQuery UI.  That can give you basic message abilities

Answer (score 0):

You could use a popup lightbox plugin, there are plenty available, but I'd recommend [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) because it's flexible, easy to use, and looks quite professional.  You can them to display any content, including simple text, buttons, forms, iframes and images.

Answer (score 0):

Have a div element hidden. Position is absolute, z-index to something greater than 0 (css).
Onclick on some button or something, have javascript change the display of this element to block.